# Many logical 'AND' operators in a row in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

From IDLE:

```
>>> a=True
>>> b=True
>>> c=True
>>> d=True
>>> e=True
>>> f=a and b and c and d and e
>>> f
True
>>> b = False
>>> f
True
```

Shouldn't the second `f` be False, since b is False?

*'If both the operands are true then condition becomes true.'*

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm

Even if it compares two names at a time, since one comparison gives False, every other comparison would be False...?

Comment: how f will be False? because of b? I didn't get your point. I think you have missed a part of your code.

Comment: f is True only if a,b,c,d and e are True? No?

Comment: Repeat this: `f=a and b and c and d and e` after you set `b` to `False`.

Comment: While the quote from Tutorials Point is correct, it is also misleadingly incomplete. `p and q` will return `q` if `p` is *truth-ish* else `p`. Python considers any object where the `__bool__()` method returns true as true. For example `3 and []` will return `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

When `f` is printed at the end, its still the value from when you first assigned it to `f`. Changing `b` after you did that evaluation does nothing to the value of `f`.

You'd have to do `f=a and b and c and d and e` again, after changing the value of `b`, to have any affect on `f`:

```
>>> a=True
>>> b=True
>>> c=True
>>> d=True
>>> e=True
>>> f=a and b and c and d and e
>>> f
True
>>> b = False
>>> f
True
>>> f=a and b and c and d and e
>>> f
False
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable f is set to the state of the conditional statement at the time it was run.  So, because the condition evaluated as True when f was defined, f will continue to be true until it is reassigned.  It won't reprocess the condition every time f is called.